# ajax request to remote site (CORS) when rest of page uses file:// protocol

Tags: angularjs, ajax, cors

page is loaded with: file:///opt/x/index.html
index.html contains angular, ui-bootstrap JS and CSS files.
it has a bunch of divs with bootstrap cols and rows.

index.html:

```
<div id="abc"/>
```

myController.js: (includes $http dependency...)

```
var elem = angular.element(document.querySelector("#abc"));
var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://www.google.com',
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : 'http://www.google.com',
        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
};
$http(req).then(function(){
    console.log (response.data);
    elem.innerHTML = response.data;
}).then(...error handling...)
```

The browser complains Allow-Control-Allow-Origin not specified error...

Answer (score 1):

Without enabling CORS or setting the server's header to allow cross origin access, use -

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security"

as target for chrome.

Comment: this seems like overkill. there must be a less extreme way to accomplish this

Comment: Yes there is - either enable CORS or set the header as I mentioned in the solution...  Take your pick.